# How to create Dropdown dynamically for Sitecore languages in Sitecore(8.2) Web forms?

Tags: sitecore-api

I want to create language selector in the site header. So for that i am trying to pick all language(/sitecore/system/Languages) from Sitecore dynamically using repeater. I am able to get language values from Sitecore but in the page i am not getting language dropdown.

My view Code :

```
    <div class="ddlCountry"> Select Language:
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpLang" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <DropDownList> 
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <listitem text=<%#: Item.Name %> runat="server"/>
             </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </DropDownList>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

My Back-end Code:

```
public partial class CountryRegionSublayout : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Item lang = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/system/Languages");

            Item[] children = lang.Children.ToArray();
            rpLang.DataSource = children;
            rpLang.DataBind();


    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the `listitem`, can you please use the `asp:DropDownList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally to display , languages in a dropdown , you should use a droplist.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="languagesDropDown" EnableViewState="False" />
```

To display the items in Key/Value pair in the dropdown, Modify the code below accordingly

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var definition in LanguageDefinitions.Definitions)
        {
            //var cultureInfo = Language.CreateCultureInfo(definition.Name);
            var listItem = new ListItem(Language.GetDisplayName(cultureInfo), definition.Name);
            this.languagesDropDown.Items.Add(listItem);
        }

        //base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

Please take reference from the InstallLanguage.aspx available in /sitecore/admin folder